# Comma separated values of dates

Tags: shell, unix

I have code that prints dates incorrectly

```
condition=`date -d "20150209" +%a`
start_date=`date -d -7day"20150209" +%Y%m%d`
end_date=`date -d -1day"20150209" +%Y%m%d`
if [ "$condition" = "Mon" ] 
then
while [ "$start_date" != "$end_date" ] 
do
Date+=$start_date,
start_date=$(date -d +1day"$start_date" +%Y%m%d)

done
echo "$Date"
fi
```

I am expecting output as

```
20150203,20150204,20150205,20150206,20150207,20150208
```

I am unable to figure out what is wrong.

Comment: And what is the *actual* output?

Comment: 20150202,20150203,20150204,20150205,20150206,20150207,20150202,20150203,20150204,20150205,20150206,20150207,

Comment: I am getting: `20150202,20150203,20150204,20150205,20150206,20150207,` from above code. What is the problem?

Comment: i need a date range from last monday to sunday.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was missing the last element in the date range.
here is the solution.

```
condition=`date -d "20150209" +%a`
start_date=`date -d -7day"20150209" +%Y%m%d`
end_date=`date -d -1day"20150209" +%Y%m%d`

while [ "$start_date" != "$end_date" ] 
do
Date+=$start_date,
start_date=$(date -d +1day"$start_date" +%Y%m%d)
done

echo "$Date$end_date"
```

if someone has a better solution please let me know.